# Java SWT Mac Unified Toolbar Layout Issue

Tags: java, macos, swt, toolbar

I am using Java SWT to make a native looking Mac OSX app with a unified toolbar. The problem is that the button I put in this toolbar is getting chopped off (Like the toolbar isn't large enough for the button):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiuer.png

Here is my code:

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);

ToolBar toolbar = shell.getToolBar();
Button toolButton = new Button(toolbar, SWT.PUSH);
toolButton.setText("This button is chopped off");
toolButton.pack();

shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
    }
}
display.dispose();
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

All the SWT widget have the method:

```
setBounds(x, y, width, height);
```

This method is used to set the dimension and the position of the widget.

So you have to do:

```
toolbar.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
toolButton.setBounds(x2, y2, w2, h2);
```

And you can draw the shell exactly as you want.

Comment: No matter what size I set the bounds to, the button would never fit in the toolbar. I tried setting the height in the bounds way higher than it needed to be, and the toolbar wouldn't change in size whatsoever.

Comment: And did you tried to modify the shell bounds? you have to define ALL the bounds properly.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc for `ToolBar` says:

> The item children that may be added to instances of this class must be
>   of type `ToolItem`.

So:

```
ToolBar toolbar = parent.getToolBar();

ToolItem toolItem = new ToolItem(toolbar, SWT.PUSH);
toolItem.setText("This toolitem is not chopped off");
```

Comment: This does not seem to be the case with the Mac unified toolbar, with apps using many different widgets in the toolbar:
https://gyazo.com/0c6acbe984172fa39af13dbfebe8daab

I started using ToolItems, but could not get the effect I wanted (Like the buttons in the previous image).

Comment: You can sort of add other controls but they are not included in the calculation of the toolbar depth.